# How to read a string into a void pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers, void, dynamic-allocation

I have been trying to read an input as string from the user inside a void pointer in C. SO i wrote something like the following:

```
void *ptr;
ptr = calloc(100,sizeof(char));
printf("Enter the string: ");
fgets(*((char *)ptr),100,stdin);
printf("You entered ");
puts(*((char *)ptr));
```

I know I may not be doing it the right way, so can anybody please help me show the right way of taking a string input in a void pointer?
I want something as

input:- Enter the string: welcome user

output:- You entered: welcome user

Comment: Why don't you have just `char *ptr = calloc(100, sizeof(char));` instead? If this is just example code to illustrate the issue then fine, but otherwise just use the right pointer type and avoid casts.

Comment: Be aware that `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

Comment: @hyde I am trying to learn how to use void pointer type as it lets me be flexible in my inputs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert the `void*` to a `char*`:

```
void *ptr;
ptr = calloc(100,sizeof(char));
printf("Enter the string: ");
fgets((char*)ptr,100,stdin);
printf("You entered ");
puts((char*)ptr);
```

`fgets` and `puts` take a pointer as first argument, so you could use `(char*)ptr` to convert the pointer.

If you write `*((char*)ptr)` you treat the void pointer as a char pointer, but also dereference it with `*` which will give you the first character. This is not what you want here.

Comment: Correct, when you add `*` next to pointer, then computer takes value that pointer points to.

Comment: You can also drop the (char *) casts

Comment: Yes. I always prefer the more verbose method. Perhaps it is because I learned C++ first...

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `(char *)` casts. Try this:

```
void *ptr;
ptr = calloc(100,sizeof(char));
printf("Enter the string: ");
fgets((char *)ptr,100,stdin);
printf("You entered ");
puts((char *)ptr);
```

Comment: But now you didn't remove the casts, but the `*`s - which, however, is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing the pointer when you pass it to fgets and fputs which means you pass the value of the first character in the memory location. Since you used calloc for the allocation you pass '\0' (the null character, zero).

Your ptr (and also `(char *)ptr`) points to some memory, i.e. its value is an address, a point in the RAM of your computer. fgets will copy chars from the console input to that memory location, byte by byte. Your expression `*((char *)ptr)` which you pass as parameter to fgets is, by contrast, *the value stored at that location.* After calloc() that value is zero, i.e. the character '\0'. Fgets thinks that's a pointer, tries to access the memory at address 0, and crashes. The same would happen with fputs, because under modern PC operating systems even a read access at "weird" addresses is not allowed for user programs. The solution is, as the others pointed out correctly, to omit the dereferencing "*".

By the way, did you not get a compiler warning? While C is not really type safe, it does have function prototypes, and most compilers warn against wrong parameter types when they are called.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want cannot be achieved due to your arguments in `fgets()`.

As the function `fgets()` take three arguments

```
1.pointer to the first cell of memory at where to store the data.
2.No of characters to be written to memeory.
3.stream pointer,from where to read.
```

But what you are doing wrong is with first argument,as you are not passing a pointer to `fgets()`.You are passing `*((char *)ptr)` it is of type `char` because of your unnecessary derefferencing.Removing external `*` will cure it because its type now becomes `char *` and you can use it as a legal argument for `fgets()`.